# Отличие активных платформ решения в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, x86-64, x86

На что влияет выбор x86 или x64 для проекта на с++ в visual studio?
(Только начинаю изучать с++)

Comment: Суть вопроса не ясна. О чем ваш вопрос? Как делать выбор между x86 и x64? Или каковы последствия выбора между x86 и x64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первую очередь на количество адресуемой памяти, но вряд ли это вас сейчас интересует.

Немножко - на производительность.

На возможность использования некоторых сторонних библиотек.

В x64 нельзя, например, встроенный ассемблер использовать...

А в целом, пока остаетесь в рамках стандарта - можете считать, что ни на что :)

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Как раз насчет количества адресуемой памяти меня и заинтересовало.
Суть в том, что я решал олимпиадные задачи по программированию и там использовались крайне большие числа. 
В пояснении к одной из задач было сказано, что число может не поместиться в 32-ух разрядный тип данных.
Есть ли информация где указаны границы размера чисел для разных типов данных в зависимости от х86 или х64?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Это где как - в Visual C++ `long` остается в 4 байта. Для автора вопроса: там вообще фундаментальные *типы данных* - но не указатели!! - по размеру те же, что и в 32-битном. Словом, для *очень* больших чисел - нет, не спасает...

Comment: @Harry Я как-то даже не ожидал такого, думал у них с GCC в этом разницы нет.